# how to write a single function in R that accepts two arguments

Tags: r

I am looking to write a function that accepts 2 arguments.

1. A single positive integer, "n"
2. A logical indicator, "all"

The function should do the following:

```
If TRUE, return the first n prime numbers as a single vector.
ELSE return only the n-th prime number.
```

The output should be:

```
genprime(7, all=TRUE)
```

> [1] 2 3 5 7 11 13 17

```
 genprime(7, all=FALSE)
```

> [1] 17

Comment: Please show what steps you have taken to create your function so far.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. We're here to help you with code that you wrote. We're not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you in putting the structure in place with below sample code:

```
generateFirstN_primesNumbers <- function(x) {
  #This function returns first x primes numbers
  # DO SOME WORK
  return(finalvector)
}

genprime <- function(n, all = TRUE) {
  allPrimes <-  generateFirstN_primesNumbers(n)
  if (all) {
    allPrimes  
  } else {
    allPrimes[length(allPrimes)]
  }
}
```

You still need to work on `generateFirstN_primesNumbers` function which will take `x` and return first X prime numbers.